# Start Tomcat on Eclipse Startup?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, tomcat, server

I've searched and cannot find anything about starting Apache Tomcat automagically when Eclipse launches.

I'm running an internal resource site on a Windows 2012 server running on a VM.
I have the problem of working in Eclipse and when my Remote Connection is terminated, Eclipse closes which stops Tomcat.

I want to add a task to my server that when it restarts Eclipse (Mars) opens and then starts Tomcat whether I am connected or not. I update my web content frequently during the day and need to make sure if my connection is broken, Tomcat is still running.

Comment: Don't run on `Tomcat` within `Eclipse` create a standalone `Tomcat` instance that runs on the server and put the application on there separate from `Eclipse`...`Tomcat` within `Eclipse` should be used for development and testing.

Comment: you'll want to look at Powershell:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can run Tomcat alone. Eclipse is just for development and testing. And you can update the resources and class files from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You should install Tomcat 7 [Windows Serivce Installer](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi)  on that server (dont install it in C:\Programms..., but somewhere where it is visible to admins). Then in Eclipse, create a new Server in the "Servers" view, pointing to that Tomcat.

That means you need to create a new "Server Runtime" (dont reuse the internal one) and a new "Local Server". Dont deploy any application, yet, even if that view shows up!

Once that wizard is done, double click the server name in the new Servers view. There, select "use Tomcat Installation" and set the "Server path" to that directory. If you cant select that, find and click the "Publish to server" button in ther "Servers" view. Finally set the deploy path to the Tomcat "webapps" directroy on the server.

After all deploy an application and check, if it appears in the newly created Tomcat "webapps" folder. "Cross fingers" and start Tomcat.